# How allowing img tag in formats can be dangerous?

Tags: 7, security

I get this recommendation form [Security review](https://drupal.org/project/security_review) module:

> It is recommended you remove the following tags from roles accessible
>   by untrusted users: img

I am wondering what real world threats can img pose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project page of [security review](https://drupal.org/project/security_review) module says

> Text formats don't allow dangerous tags (protecting against XSS)
>
> Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attacks are a type of injection, in which
>   malicious scripts are injected into otherwise benign and trusted web
>   sites. XSS attacks occur when an attacker uses a web application to
>   send malicious code, generally in the form of a browser side script,
>   to a different end user. Flaws that allow these attacks to succeed are
>   quite widespread and occur anywhere a web application uses input from
>   a user within the output it generates without validating or encoding
>   it.
>
> An attacker can use XSS to send a malicious script to an unsuspecting
>   user. The end user’s browser has no way to know that the script should
>   not be trusted, and will execute the script. Because it thinks the
>   script came from a trusted source, the malicious script can access any
>   cookies, session tokens, or other sensitive information retained by
>   the browser and used with that site. These scripts can even rewrite
>   the content of the HTML page.

For example you can use img tag as below for XSS attack..

```
<img src='#' onerror=alert(1) />
```

Comment: Thanks Anil for the info. So how can we allow users of a social site (which obviously are not all trusted) to upload images while avoiding this threat?

Comment: @alfish, this is not a forum, so please don't use the comment field to ask a new question.  Instead, press the "Ask question" button and ask a *new* question.  What you ask in the comment above is a good question, but I am not going to answer it before it is asked as a *new* question. (Refer back to this question to provide context.)

Comment: Here it is:http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/114903/how-safely-allow-untrusted-users-to-use-img-tag